# Javascript replace comma separated characters by using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace `@parm1,@parm2,@parm3...` etc with comma separated values using regular. how can i do this ?

**Example**

**Input Data**

My Name is `@parm1` and My father Name is `@parm2` and also my nick name is `@parm1` and i live in `@parm3`

**Replace with**

```
James,Nortain,TEST Address
```

**Result**

My Name is `James` and My father Name is `Nortain` and also my nick name is `@parm1` and i live in `TEST Address`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @putvande i am new and i do it using loop,but its not working so i want to do it using Regx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```js
var str = "My Name is @parm1 and My father Name is @parm2 and also my nick name is @parm1 and i live in @parm3";
var values = "James,Nortain,TEST Address".split(",");
var result = str.replace(/@parm(\d+)/gi, function(a,b){
    return values[b-1] || a
});

document.write(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will replace each of the `name` separated by `,` using `for`:

```
var str = 'My Name is @parm1 and My father Name is @parm2 and also my nick name is @parm1 and i live in @parm3';

var strName = 'James,Nortain,TEST Address';

var names = strName.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace('@parm' + (i + 1), names[i]);
}

alert(str);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4cq08hbc/

Comment: Yeah - that's better.  Also more correct than the other answer posted, as the OP's example result didn't replace the second `@parm1` value (whether that's intentional or not...?!)